# How can I add a new language auto complete and suggestions for sublime text?

Tags: python, autocomplete, yaml, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I'm trying to create a new language support for Sublime Text 3. I've been successfully creating a syntax highlighting using `YAML`, but i'd like to get some help when I'm writing the code, like Sublime Text do with `CSS` or `PHP`, that I start typing a command and it recognizes and shows a list with the possible commands and when I choose it, they're written in the code automatically. I just fill it.
How can I do this?

Maybe if you have some tips to make syntax highlight, it would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) work for your? You could then declare a snippet like

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[-Content you want to fill here-]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>-Implicit key binder-</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

and save it under `Packages/User`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using some snippets as well, but they don't help as much as I wanted. I researched a little bit and I discovered that they use a ".sublime-completions" file.
But the Snippets are helping me as well... Thanks ^^